# Java inheritance program output issue

Tags: java, inheritance

I have been working this program for a while now, but still not able to get the correct output.

The output should resemble the picture below, but I am getting a different wrong output.
[image: Output]

The test class can be found in this link [StockObserverTest class](http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~crahn/COP4814/StockObserverTest.java)

PricesDisplay class code:

```
@Override
public void update (Map<String,Double> priceMap) 
{
    this.priceMap = priceMap;
    display();      //calling display method
}

@Override
public void display() {
    //print line
    System.out.printf("Portfolio #%s, ASD = %.2f, ADM = %.2f, "
            + "AAC = %.2f, AFAS = %.2f %n", ticker, priceMap.get("ASD"), priceMap.get("ADM"), 
            priceMap.get("AAC"), priceMap.get("AFAS"));
 }
}
```

I am not understanding as to what I can do to print them out to look like the desired output.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], ideally with expected/actual output in *text* rather than as images... and explain *why* you expect particular behaviour. (It's hard to correct misconceptions when we don't know your thought process.)

Comment: I think you are passing the same map (why map?) to method `update` twice so you have the same output. Check you code and make sure you have right order of data flow during processing.

Comment: Sorry, not understanding what you mean passing priceMap twice. Are you able to explain a little bit more if possible, please? I am really confused with this program.